# How to programmatically select DataGrid row with criteria?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

Is there a way to select a DataGrid row by referencing the row ID?

I am selecting a DataGrid programatically via the code below,

```
public static void GetFocusOfSelectedRow(DataGrid datagrid)
    {                       
        object oItem = datagrid.Items[0];
        datagrid.SelectedItem = oItem;
        datagrid.ScrollIntoView(oItem);
    }
```

This just selects the first row in the DataGrid.

I was hoping to be able to specify which row to select by using the primary key. ie, say a row has a primary key ID of `123456`. How could I get the rows index number with the ID of `123456` via LINQ or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your items collection to a collection of Type that you know it has a property you want to filter.

Try

```
public static void GetFocusOfSelectedRow(DataGrid datagrid)
    {
        ItemCollection items = datagrid.Items;
        List<SomeType> collection = new List<SomeType>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            SomeType obj = item as SomeType ;
            if(obj != null)
                collection.Add(obj);
        }

        SomeType result = collection.Where(a => a.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        datagrid.SelectedItem = result;
        datagrid.ScrollIntoView(result);
    }
```

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to format my answer. You are right it should

Comment: I up voted your answer as it helped to get what I needed, I will accept it now. Cheers and thanks for the help.